# get id where price is max in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

#### My table is:

```
id  code    batch price    qty
---|----- |----- |-----|---------
1  | 107  | 1    | 39  | 399 
2  | 107  | 1    | 39  | 244
3  | 107  | 2    | 40  | 555
4  | 108  | 1    | 70  | 300
5  | 108  | 2    | 60  | 200
6  | 109  | 2    | 50  | 500
7  | 109  | 2    | 50  | 600
8  | 110  | 2    | 75  | 700
```

My desired result is (i want this result as output)

```
id  code    batch price  
---|----- |----- |-----|
3  | 107  | 2    | 40  |
4  | 108  | 1    | 70  |
3  | 109  | 2    | 50  | 
8  | 110  | 2    | 75  |
```

i write this query

```
SELECT `id`,`code`,`batch` max(`price`) FROM `table_name` where `qty` > 0  group by `code`
```

my output is

```
id  code    batch price  
---|----- |----- |-----|
1  | 107  | 1    | 40  |
4  | 108  | 1    | 70  |
6  | 109  | 2    | 50  | 
8  | 110  | 2    | 75  |
```

i need id and batch where the price is max

Comment: Kindly try this : 
SELECT `id`,`code`,`batch` max(`price`) as prs FROM `table_name` where `qty` > 0  group by `code` order by prs

Comment: try my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use join on the max value grouped  by code

```
select  a.id, a.code, a.batch, b.max_price
from table_name a 
inner join  (
  select code, max(price) as max_price
  from table_name
  group by code 
) b on a.code = b.code  and a.price = b.max_price
```

and if you have more that a row with same code, price you could use

```
select  max(a.id), a.code, a.batch, b.max_price
from table_name a 
inner join  (
  select code, max(price) as max_price
  from table_name
  group by code 
) b on a.code = b.code  and a.price = b.max_price   
group by a.code, a.batch, b.max_price
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get highest record per group

```
select *
from demo a
where (
  select count(*)
  from demo b
  where a.code = b.code
  and case when a.price = b.price then a.id < b.id else a.price < b.price end
) = 0
```

> I assume id is auto increment so in case there is a tie in max price from groups you can use a `CASE` to pick the latest id

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b432/5)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,batch from table_name order by price desc limit 0,1
```

- Sort by desc with price
- Select the top row using limit

Answer (score 0):

Order by the price and then limit the result to 1 :)

```
SELECT id, batch 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number group by `code` and in the descending order of `price` columns. Then select the rows having row number 1.

**Query**

```
select t1.`id`, t1.`code`, t1.`batch`, t1.`price` from (
    select `id`, `code`, `batch`, `price`, (
        case `code` when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `code` end 
    ) as `rn`
    from `MyTable` t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by `code`, `price` desc 
)t1 
where t1.`rn` = 1
order by `code`;
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86160b/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `id`,`code`,`batch`, `price`
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `qty` > 0
GROUP BY `code` HAVING `price` =  max(`price`)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this
       SELECT MAX(`price`) AS price, `id`, `batch`
       FROM table_name

Comment: your query is wrong.  error `Invalid use of group function `

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand you need single result or multiple. but this works fine if you need only max id.

```
 SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id=(
        SELECT max(price) FROM table
        )
```

**Note** : if the value of max(id) is not unique, multiple rows are returned.

Comment: i need single record (group by code but price is max and get those row where price is max)

Comment: this code works according to your requirement. try by putting table name and all other field.

Comment: dear @BilalAhmed. its because price dont have value that matches id.